# Accessing tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, pygame, tuples

So, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this yet. I'm making a map parser for a game, and so far I have a three dimensional list "mapData" in the module "maps". It stores tuples that contain the tile and floor ids. So, when I'm trying to draw the floor, I call

```
if maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y][0] == 0: c.blit(maps.grass, tileRect)
```

to draw the grass for example, and to draw the tiles I call

```
if maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y][1] == 1: c.blit(maps.tallGrass, tileRect)
```

to draw the tall grass. Though, the [0] and [1] is what I'm confused about. They are trying to reference the first and second element of the tuple respectively, but I suspect I am doing that wrong, as I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Just to help, the list "mapData" is initialized as follows:

```
mapData = [[[0 for y in range(19)] for x in range(25)] for m in range(mapAmount)]
mapData[mapIndex["spawn"]][5][5] = (0, 1)
```

with "mapIndex" being a dictionary of integers that specify what map is what.

So, I need to know how to get a specific element from a tuple, preferably without using x, y = tuple because that takes a bit more memory, as it has to store the variable. and this is in the rendering loop. If that is the only way to do it, then that is ok by me though. Thanks!

As a side question, does anyone have better idea of deciding what tile to draw other than making a giant if+elif statement in the rendering code?

EDIT: I tried this code:

```
 floor, tile = maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y]

 #draw floor
 if floor == 0: c.blit(maps.grass, tileRect)

 #draw tiles
 if tile == 1: c.blit(maps.tallGrass, tileRect)
```

and got the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Concerning your side question: Dictionaries can replace often vast if-elif-chains.

Comment: `maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y]` is not a tuple (or any sequence type) like you excpect it to be, but an integer. To figure out why, try printing it or set a [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) breakpoint and inspect it.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I have tried to implement that, but I've gotten an error concerning something to have to do with the way I set it up. I'll try to set it up again once this is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Hyperboreus, your mapData item is broken. e.g.  x=[(1,2)]*5; x[1][0]
1
works fine

Comment: I tried the exact code in IDLE and it seemed to work fine. I will try pdb then, though I have never used it before.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your lookup code - `maps.mapData[mapIndex][x][y][0]` is a perfectly valid way to check the 1st element of a tuple stored as the value of a three-dimensional array. Something must be off with your initialization code. Although it does stand out to me that in this line `mapIndex` has to be an integer so it can be an array index, and in your initialization code it has to be a dict with `"spawn"` as a key - you'd get a different exception if that hadn't changed but that still has "code smell" to me.

Comment: @qwertyman How about posting the relevant code?

Comment: Never mind again, I didn't solve the problem. What relevant code would you be referencing?

Comment: The problem is that you only assign a tuple for `mapIndex["spawn"]][5][5]`, but all the others are initialized with `0` from the line above.

Comment: @LukasGraf Oh my gosh, that makes perfect sense. I'll try that now, thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you decompose your statements a bit: Split them into several temporary variables that you do your work on, and give them meaningful names.

Comment: @LukasGraf That's what I'm trying to do by splitting it into separate files as it helps me think clearer, but I'm very bad at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LukasGraf, the problem has been solved. Not all the variables in the list were initialized as tuples, so I changed this initialization code

```
mapData = [[[0 for y in range(19)] for x in range(25)] for m in range(mapAmount)]
```

to this

```
mapData = [[[(0, 0) for y in range(19)] for x in range(25)] for m in range(mapAmount)]
```

to make the default value in the list the tuple (0, 0) instead of 0.